# How to Convert Resized image to binary

Tags: python, io, binary, python-imaging-library

I am saving  profile images in a Mysql Blob. follwoing function is getting image, resized and display it and at last save it (through another function) in a table.

```
def get_image(self, event):
        filetypes = (('image files', '*.png'), ('All files', '*.*'))
        filepath = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)
        if len(filepath) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror(
                'showerror', 'You did not select file.')
            return
        else:
            
            img = Image.open(filepath)
            img = img.resize((180, 180))
            self.defualt_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            self.pic_label.config(image=self.defualt_image)
            file = open(filepath, 'rb')
            self.binaryfile = file.read()
            file.close()
```

I am displaying a resized image but i could'nt save that resized image rahter i am opening again a full image and saving it. All i want is to save that resized image to db rather than orignal image.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You say you want to reduce the size of an image and store it in MySQL, but your code only resizes an image then **reads** something (not writes) and does nothing with MySQL. It also includes a load of unnecessary Tkinter stuff and doesn't have all the necessary `import` statements.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, full module is very long, i have only shear the method where i get an image from file dialog, resize it and show it on a tk.Label widget. after that i again open that file in binary mode and save data to self.binaryfile variable which later on i save it to mysql in another method. i only need to convert img variable data to binary and assigned it to self.binaryfile. i actuly want to skip 'file = open(filepath, 'rb') part.